# Class conditional with vue js

Tags: class, vue.js, foreach, v-for

I've done a weekly calendar view with events on it and have free or selected events. I tried to give the selected events different background color but I think I'm missing something so If someone can help me with that it will be great.

To give more details about the code : 
I have an array of events (objects) when the event is free the user_id is 0.
So i put a boolean variable in data and i update it during the render of the function of displayEvents . I know it's not the best way but Icouldn't find an other solution that works . 
so ofcourse it's returning "an infinite loop issue " 
Please if someone can see a better way to get the same results i'll be glad.

this is my code:

```
//the template 
------------------------------
<table>
   <tbody>
     <tr v-for="(time, index) in times" :key="index">
     <td class="headcol">{{time}}</td>
     <td v-for="(dayDate, index) in calendarWeek.weekDates" :key="index"  >
      <div v-show="displayEvent(dayDate, time)"
       :class="[event, selected !== 0 ? 'event_selected':'']"
      @click="toggleSelect(dayDate, time)" >
        {{formatDate(dayDate)}}
        <br>{{time}}
        </div>
     </td>
   </tr>
   </tbody>
 </table>  

  // the script 
   ---------------------

  data(){
     return:{  
     .....
    selected = false,
     }},

   methods:{
 //display Events
     displayEventC(dayDate, time) {
     if ( this.$store.state.token ) {
       return this.events.find(el=>{
         if( el.event_date === this.formatDate(dayDate) && el.start_time === time && el.user_id === 0 ){
        this.selected=false;
         return el
         }
         if( el.event_date === this.formatDate(dayDate) && el.start_time === time &&  el.user_id == this.$store.state.userId ){ 
         this.selected=true;
         return el
         } 
         });
     }
     else{
     return this.events.find(el=>{
         if( el.event_date === this.formatDate(dayDate) && el.start_time === time && el.user_id === 0 ){
         return el
         }
         });
     }
   },
```

this is what i have as a display 
[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TPaVk.jpg)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TPaVk.jpg)

Comment: Not sure what you want to achieve, you're not showing what `this.elements` are, but this code `return this.events.forEach(el => {
          console.log(el.user_id)
          return el.user_id
        });` doesnt do anything.

Comment: if you check the image this return 17 or 0  this is the user_id

Comment: I meant it doesn't do anything meaningful and doesnt `return` anything meaningful for the computed property. It just loops through the array.

Comment: okey , so if i want to return the user id on each event displayed do you have an idea how i can do it . the events is an array of objects . how can i get that inside the template ?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if I understood you properly, but this is my suggestion:

```
//div in v-fored td
:class="dynamicClass(dayDate)"

// script

computed: {
  dynamicClass () {
    return (day) => {
      let event = this.events.find(ev => ev.event_date === day);
      return event.user_id !== 0 ? 'event_selected':'event_free'
    }
  } 
}
```

Comment: Itried your answer but it doesn't really work so I did somethiing else it's givng me my answer but it return a warning that there is an infinite loop . I'll update ùy queston maybe you can help me .

Comment: Try without the internal function: `dynamicClass (day) {
          let event = this.events.find(ev => ev.event_date === day);
      return event.user_id !== 0 ? 'event_selected':'event_free'
    }`

Comment: ok , i've just updated my question sorry for the late , so tell me what you think  :)

Comment: it return an error thar the user_id is of undefined . i think cause the event that the cmputed function return is an array . i tried with a foreach function it was the same error. Iknow it's not easy to understand someone else logic

Answer (score 0):

the solution was to add a condition that the typeof my object should not be undefined and iused the idea in the answer of Eggon